# proof that the Fourier series of $ f\ast g $ uniformly converge.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let   $f,g$  be   $2\pi$-periodic piecewise continuous functions.

 proof that the Fourier series of $ f\ast g $  uniformly converge.

 Where $ f\ast g $ denotes the convolution operator between $f$ and $g$.

What I have so far:

- to show that the Fourier series of $ f\ast g $ uniformly converges I need to show that $ f\ast g $ is continuous and that $ f\ast g(\pi) =  f\ast g (-\pi)$. finally I need to show that the derivative of $ f\ast g $ is piecewise continuous.
- $ f\ast g(-\pi) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(-\pi-t)g(t)dt=
  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\pi-t)g(t)dt= f\ast g(\pi)$ where the second equality holds by $2\pi$-periodicity of $f$.

how do I know that $ f\ast g $ is continuous and that the derivative of $ f\ast g $ is piecewise continuous?

Comment: How do you know that $f\ast g$ is differentiable?

Comment: When I come to think about it, I guess I don't have a way to know that. Because I need to know that either f or g are differentiable as well as absolutely integrable and this is not known. So what would be a good direction to go to in this proof?

Comment: I don't know the solution. Maybe you could try the following. The partial Fourier series $S_N[f\ast g](x)$ can be expressed as a convolution with the Dirichlet kernel. Therefore:
$$S_N[f\ast g](x)=f\ast g\ast D_N(x).$$ You could try showing that this expression is uniformly Cauchy as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: The same question has been asked a few weeks ago, but atm I can't find it. In the meantime, try to use Plancherels formula and use how convolution acts on the Fourier side.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\hat f(n)$ and $\hat g(n)$ be the (complex) coefficients of $f$ and $g$. By Plancherel's formula
$$
\sum|\hat f(n)|^2=\int_{\mathbb{T}}|f(x)|^2\,dx<\infty,\quad\sum|\hat g(n)|^2=\int_{\mathbb{T}}|g(x)|^2\,dx<\infty.
$$
We also know
$$
\widehat{f\ast g}(n)=\hat f(n)\,\hat g(n).
$$
Then, by the  Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
\sum|\widehat{f\ast g}(n)|=\sum|\hat f(n)\,\hat g(n)|\le\Bigl(\sum|\hat f(n)|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}\Bigl(\sum|\hat g(n)|^2\Bigr)^{1/2}<\infty.
$$
Where $\mathbb{T}$ denotes the circle $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I hope you dont mind me fixing up the typos.

Comment: Of course not. I approved them as soon as I was informed about them.

Comment: @YaG32 Can you see how this shows continuity?

Comment: The series is uniformly convergent.